# Which compiler (Sun Studio or gcc ) to choose while porting from Solaris Sparc to Linux x86

Tags: optimization, gcc, compiler-construction, sunstudio

We have decide to port our application that currently runs on solaris sparc to linux x86 system. Which compiler, Sun Studio or GNU gcc would be more beneficial to use on linux? Which one would produce at a good level of optimized binaries?

Any help or directions would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Now, Sun Studio is owned by Oracle, and there is lots of incertitude about where it's going next. Many people would advise GCC, which is the de facto standard compiler on Linux, and has a much bigger user community.